# soapUI combine more mock services

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mocking, soapui

I would like to create a mock service with soapUI, but not from a single wsdl, but from several, and at the end, create a single WAR that can be deployed. Theoretically that's possible, if I create more soapUI projects with the different wsdls and then start each mock service separately. But how is this possible to package these different services to one WAR instance, and then connect to the services on different URLs.

Thnaks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create 1 SOAPUI project.

Right click on the project and add click Add WSDL.

Repeat for all WSDL's you want to add.

Right click on a imported WSDL and click Generate MockService

Repeat for all services you wish to mock.

To deploy right click on the project and click Deploy As War, Include Global settings, Enable WebUI.

Set the MockServiceEndpoint to http://:
Set the War File (which will be the context root)